# Illegal BitCast while compiling opencl kernel

Tags: llvm, opencl, llvm-ir, llc

The below bitcast instruction is throwing me an Illegal Bitcast error, can someone point what the problem is?

```
%opencl.image1d_ro_t = type opaque
%struct.dev_image_t = type { i8*, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32, i32 }

%astype = bitcast %opencl.image1d_ro_t addrspace(1)* %image to %struct.dev_image_t*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting from address space 1 to the default address space, 0. That won't work, [as the documentation says](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#bitcast-to-instruction). Each address space is independent.

Address spaces are meant for things like programs that have some garbage-collected and some manually managed memory. The pointer points to two profoundly different kinds of memory.